# Run trigger by LastRow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I've already spent days trying to figure out how to write the script for what I need. Here's what  I currently have

```
function setUpTrigger(){

ScriptApp.newTrigger('LOOKUP')
.forForm('11jqQgzXiCT0XH8fAlfFS8y3_XgdY69L5QfoHAFwW0rk')
.onFormSubmit()
.create();

}

function LOOKUP() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const wsLogsheet = ss.getSheetByName ("Respondent Log")
const wsLimit = ss.getSheetByName("Limit")
const limitData=  wsLimit.getRange(2,1, wsLimit.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues()
const searchValue =  wsLogsheet .getRange("B2").getValue()
const matchRow = limitData .find(r => r[0] == searchValue)
const match = matchRow ? matchRow[2]: null
wsLogsheet.getRange("J2").setValue(match)
```

I want to set it up so that it runs on each lastrow (column J) with each new submission. The previous entries will also remain unchanged with each trigger. Meaning if I change the values on the lookup data, previous entries will not be affected. This is the modified code but won't run.

```
function setUpTrigger(){

ScriptApp.newTrigger('LOOKUP')
.forForm('11jqQgzXiCT0XH8fAlfFS8y3_XgdY69L5QfoHAFwW0rk')
.onFormSubmit()
.create();
}

function LOOKUP() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const wsLogsheet = ss.getSheetByName ("Respondent Log")
const wsLimit = ss.getSheetByName("Limit")
const limitData=  wsLimit.getRange(2,1, 
wsLimit.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues()
const searchValue =  wsLogsheet 
.getRange(wsLogsheet.getLastRow(),2).getValue();
const matchRow = limitData .find(r => r[0] == searchValue)
const match = matchRow ? matchRow[2]: null
wsLogsheet.getRange(wsLogsheet.getLastRow(),10).setValue(match);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The script has a function to create a form trigger to call a function that apparently belongs to a project contained by a spreadsheet. This don't work. Instead you might create a spreadsheet trigger and take advantage of the event object. If you need further help, please provide more details, i.e. if the form is already linked to the spreadsheet and in such case the name of the sheet receiving the form submission values.

Comment: Hi, the form is already linked to the spreadsheet. I am able to get it to run if I set it to just a single cell/range as the script I've initially posted but whenever I change the following to lastrow, it just comes up blank

const searchValue =  wsLogsheet .getRange(wsLogsheet.getLastRow(),2).getValue();
wsLogsheet.getRange(wsLogsheet.getLastRow(),10).setValue(match);

Comment: Might I suggest, after `const matchRow = ` include a line `console.log("matchRow = "+matchRow);`

Answer (score 0):

#### Try it this way:

```
function LOOKUP(e) {
  const log = e.source.getSheetByName("Respondent Log")
  const lim = e.source.getSheetByName("Limit")
  const limvs = lim.getRange(2, 1, lim.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues()
  const searchValue = log.getRange("B2").getValue();
  const row = limvs.find(r => r[0] == searchValue)
  log.getRange("J2").setValue(row[2]);
}
function setUpTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('LOOKUP').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onFormSubmit().create()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm getting an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined. I've also tried adding lastrow to my script for b2 and j2 but the column remains blank

Comment: You cannot run this function from the script editor.  It require the event object from the trigger

Comment: I am able to get it to work with just a single reference/range (cells b2 and j2) however, when I run the script once I changed the following to lastrow range, it no longer works

const searchValue =  wsLogsheet .getRange(wsLogsheet.getLastRow(),2).getValue();
wsLogsheet.getRange(wsLogsheet.getLastRow(),10).setValue(match);

Comment: Please post your current code in your question

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question to show my current code. Thank you